# Sumup or order values of an array

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

with the following code I get the total persons of the individual reservations. However, I would like to have the values ​​summarized depending on the start date ,and not as a total of all reservations.

I need the total amount **of persons** per day. So the values ​​for which the start date is the same. Not the total persons of all days.

```
    $total_count = 0; // Initializing
                    
                    
        $reservation_ids = get_posts( array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type'   => 'arb_reservation',
            'post_status' => 'paid',
            'start_date'  => 'start_date',
            'fields'      => 'ids',
        ) );
                    
                    
                    // Loop through reservation Ids
    foreach ( $reservation_ids as $reservation_id ) {
   $reservation = new ARB_Reservation( $reservation_id );
    $count   = array_sum( $reservation->get_person_counts() );

    $total_count += $count;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you inclusive to give you the count and WP_Query, see below:

```
// define target date
$today = date( 'Y-m-d' );

// build query
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'arb_reservation',
    'post_status' => 'paid',
    'date_query' => array(
        array( 
            'after' => $today,
            'before' => $today,
            'inclusive'  => true,
        )
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// example count
echo count( $query->have_posts() );
```

Comment: Thanks Phil, I'm sorry I mean not the amount of order itself. I edit my question. I mean the amount of persons per day. But I won't give a initial date. I want an automatically sumup / combine of the amount of persons per start_date.
e.g.
02.02.21 - 3 persons - reservation 1
02.02.21 - 8 persons - reservation 2
02.02.21 - 12 persons - reservation 3
04.02.21 - 4 persons - reservation 4
04.02.21 - 23 persons - reservation 5
04.02.21 - 2 persons - reservation 6
and so on.

-->total amount 02.02.21 - 23 persons
--> total amount 04.02.21 - 29 persons